# Remove server name while sending mail

Tags: linux, rhel-7

While sending mails using sendmail, the domain name is getting appended to the from and the to email addresses. My requirement is not to have that domain name. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: It would help if you let us know what MTA you are using. Was it Sendmail or postfix (which also has sendmail) or something else?  What have you tried?

Comment: i am using sendmail